# How do I use PHP/cURL to connect to a private GitHub repo and pull down files?

Tags: php, curl, github, oauth-2.0, access-token

I'm trying to use PHP/cURL to connect to a private GitHub repo I created and pull down files from that repo.

I fundamentally understand how to make cURL requests in PHP, how to send over headers in the request, etc. I'm also fine with the basic structure of the GitHub API for grabbing files, etc. For example, I understand the basic request structure for the following API page:
https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/

However, where I'm struggling is with things like the authentication outlined on the following page:
https://developer.github.com/v3/#authentication

How do I get an Oauth 2 token? There's no real explanation on the page or any of the related documentation.
Also, I'm assuming that I probably need some special kind of key (maybe it's the token) to prove that I have authorized access to the private repo I'm trying to access, but I'm not sure what to do for that either.

If I can get the token (and possibly the API key for the private repo as well), then I think I can make the requests and do what I need to do, but the token generation/usage process is very unclear.
Can someone please provide some guidance on how to approach this?
Thank you.

---

**Edit/Answer:**

Thanks again to Adolfo Eloy in explaining how to do this.

Based on his advice, I ended up going to my profile settings, clicking on **Developer settings**, **Personal access tokens**, **Generate new token**, and then clicking the top checkbox for **repo** to get full rights to the private repos.

After doing that, I copied the generated access key and pasted it into Postman as follows:
I added a new header with the key `Authorization` and a value of `token generated-token-string`.

I then made a request to the following URL:
https://api.github.com/repos/*user-name*/*repo-name*

From there, I was able to use the GitHub API (https://developer.github.com/v3/) to get what I needed.
Hopefully this will help anyone else stuck in the same situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to visit [GitHub developers](https://github.com/settings/developers) so you can register an OAuth2 application. Then you have to fill the registering form with your app info such as the name and the url of your application. The most important field now is the **Authorization callback URL**. This URL will be used by GitHub to redirect you (or the user of your application) to your previously registered application.

After filling all the fields, click on Register Application and GitHub will provide client credentials which will be the `client_id` and `client_secret` values.

Copy these credentials to assemble an Authorization URL to start requesting for an access token. Take a look at the authorization URL that I have built below (in my case I am using a client_id identified by `daaaaaa75d1c77526e9` - and of course I think this client ID does not exists).

```
https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?client_id=daaaaaa75d1c77526e9
&scope=gist&state=xdfads2342&allow_signup=false
&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/callback
```

The parameters sent are detailed as follows:

- **client_id**: the id of your registered application
- **scope**: the permission you are requesting for GitHub (GitHub provides all available scopes for you at [Available scopes](https://developer.github.com/apps/building-oauth-apps/scopes-for-oauth-apps/#available-scopes))
- **state**: a randomly generated number that you have to use in your application to avoid CSRF Attack (to better understand why you can read the OAuth 2.0 specification - RFC 6749)
- **allow_signup**: better explained at GitHub docs
- **redirect_uri**: the URI of your application to receive the authorization code that may be provided in case the use authorizes the usage of his resources.

If the authorization phase runs successfuly, then the following URL might appear on your web browser (with different values for code and state):

```
http://localhost:8080/callback?code=24234324324234&state=xdfads2342
```

Now, all you have to do is to request an access token by sending a POST request to `/login/oauth/access_token` endpoint using a cURL tool as presented bellow:

```
curl -X POST "https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token" 
-d "client_id=daaaaaa75d1c77526e9&client_secret=blablablabla
&code=24234324324234&state=xdfads2342 
&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/callback"
```

Then you should receive the following result on your terminal (with a different access token of course):

```
access_token=23424234234324324lkj23l4kj32&scope=gist&token_type=bearer
```

Now, to use this access token you have to declare the http header as follows:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer 23424234234324324lkj23l4kj32" "http://api.github.com/gists/public"
```

Comment: Adolfo, thanks a lot for this extremely thorough answer. This makes a lot of sense. (I just wish GitHub would explain this sort of thing in their own docs.) I'm still a bit confused about the `redirect_url` though and the best value to use for my use case.

Comment: Specifically, in my case, I will use the GitHub repo as a central repository for syncing up with other remote copies of the code base by having a script that makes daily calls to the GH repo to check for various things. For that purpose, I need to get an OAuth2 token each time, but do I still need to specify a callback URL? Or rather, if I have to, what kind of URL should I use? Do I need to stand up a different server with it's own URL just for handling these OAuth2 requests? Again, a bit confused about that part. Thank you.

Comment: This `redirection_url` was designed so our app is allowed to receive the user's authorization. So, it relies on an interactive process between your client app, Github and the user. The way you want to use GitHub, it seems to better register your application using another strategy. At Developer Settings you can register your app using 2 other different approaches (Github App or generate a personal access token). Than I believe you won't need to create a new token every time.

Comment: Adolfo, that was the key (no pun intended)! Thank you so much. I went to Developer Settings under my profile and generated a personal access token with access to private repositories, and I was able to make requests to the repo by setting the Authorization header to token token-string. Thank you.